# Inoperative OpenMP optimisation

Tags: c++, vector, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to optimize a greedy function with OpenMP as a beginner.

Unfortunately, I've tried several thing without success. I'm simply searching, for the first element of each pair in a vector, the index of its occurence (unique) as second element in the same vector. Here is my code :

```
std::vector<int> function(std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >& pair_vector)
{
    unsigned int size = pairVector.size();
    std::vector<int> resVector(size);

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            resVector[i] = -pairVector[i].first;

            for (unsigned int j = i; j < size; ++j)
            {
                if(pairVector[i].first == pairVector[j].second)
                {
                    resVector[i] = size - j; 
                    break;                                          
                }
            }                                                   
        }
    }

    return resVector;
}
```

Is there anyone seeing what's wrong with that ??

Thank.

EDIT:

The number of pairs in the vector can be over 1.000.000. The result is the same in both implementations. And even for that size of datas, there is not speed up (even with different schedule types).

Comment: How is it failing? Can you give an example of what the serial code is producing as well as the parallel code? How do they differ?

Comment: Both codes are producing the same time. Maybe a little more for the parallel implementation (this seems logical).

Comment: You mean they give the same result but you're just not getting a speed up with the parallel version?

Comment: How long does this take serially? Is there enough work to make parallelization worthwhile? The time for the i iterations is clearly hugely variable (with the shortest case only a few tens of instructions), so try schedule(dynamic), possibly also with a chunk size, or at least schedule(static,1).

Comment: The result is the same (parallel or not). However, there isn't any speed up.

Comment: I truly think that a parallelisation is needed here. My vector is about to contain over than 1 000 000 pairs. Anyway, even on a little 10 instructions, the parallelisation should improve the execution time (significant or not) for that size of datas.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: "Both codes are producing the same time. Maybe a little more for the parallel implementation (this seems logical)". Let me guess, you use `clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to measure the elapsed time? Or you have `OMP_NUM_THREADS` set to `1`. Or you have forgotten to enable OpenMP support with your compiler. As you can see, one could only speculate until you provide more information.

Comment: You're not using any of the clauses to the `#pragma omp for` to indicate which variables are shared and which are private to each thread. Related, your index variable for the outer loop (`i`) is declared after the pragma, so you can't tell the pragma that it is a private variable. Move `unsigned int i` to the beginning of your function, leaving only `i=0` within the initializer.

Comment: What does omp_get_num_threads() function output? Did you check the CPU utilization? Does it show utilization on all cores? Did you compile with -fopemnp flag?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, variables declared within parallel regions are private and those declare outside are shared. OpenMP will automatically make the iterator of a `parallel for` clause priviate even if is declared outside a parallel region (which it's not in the OPs case anyway). The OPs code is fine as is shown now.

Comment: The OP has not provided enough information to answer the question. The question should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm you are using appears to be O(N^2) but it should be possible in O(NlogN). Even if the O(NlogN) solution is serial, it should still provide a net speedup.

Here is an O(NlogN) solution to your problem. The code could be tightened up by better use of STL.

```
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> function(std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >& pair_vector) {
    unsigned int size = pair_vector.size();
    std::vector<int> resVector(size);

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > firsts(size);
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > seconds(size);
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        firsts[i] = std::pair<int, int>(pair_vector[i].first, i);
        seconds[i] = std::pair<int, int>(pair_vector[i].second, size-i);
    }

    std::sort(firsts.begin(), firsts.end());
    std::sort(seconds.begin(), seconds.end());

    int j=0;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
      while ((seconds[j].first < firsts[i].first)&&(j<size))
        j++;
      if (seconds[j].first == firsts[i].first)
        resVector[firsts[i].second] = seconds[j].second;
      else
        resVector[firsts[i].second] = -firsts[i].first;
    }

    return resVector;
}
```